# Extracting Categorical Variables from Data Source in Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api, data-manipulation

I currently have a table that looks like this:

```
Date          Variable    Value
1995-10-01       X          50
1995-10-01       Y          60
1995-08-03       X          70
1995-08-03       Y          90
```

And want to reshape it so that it looks like this:

```
Date          X   Y
1995-10-01   50   60
1995-08-03   70   90
```

This is easily doable in R using the `cast` function from the `reshape` package with the command `df <- cast(df, ... ~ variable)`. I have two questions:

1) Can this form of dataset modification be done using a calculated field with an R script?

2) Is there a native way for such modification to be done in Tableau?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a R question?

Comment: I apologize if the tagging was misleading. It's more of a Tableau question, but since Tableau has backend integration with R, I figured it would be good to tag R as well.

Comment: Move your `variable` variable to the columns bars.

Answer (score 1):

This is your data as it would be setup by default:

[Step 1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCP2q.png)

All, you need to do is to move the `variable` field up to the `Columns` section:

[Step 2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfUUw.png)